# Authenticated with "Login-AzureRmAccount -ServicePrincipal" but no subscription is set?

Tags: azure, authentication, client-certificates, service-principal

I've successfully created a self-signed certificate with application & service principle using the New-AzureRmADApplication and New-AzureRmADServicePrincipal cmdlets.

I can execute the login using this command after retrieving the certificate:

```
Login-AzureRmAccount -ServicePrincipal -CertificateThumbprint $cert.Thumbprint -TenantId $tenantID -ApplicationId $applicationID
```

However, the SubscriptionId/SubscriptionName attributes of this authentication display as blank:

```
Environment           : AzureCloud

Account               : ********************

TenantId              : ********************

SubscriptionId        : 

SubscriptionName      : 

CurrentStorageAccount :
```

Subsquently, this command works!

```
$secret = Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $vaultName -Name $keyName
```

What is confusing to me is that I am able to retrieve a AzureKeyVaultSecret in my DEV subscription, but I do not understand how this cmdlet knows which of my subscriptions to use???  I intend to create the same vault in my PROD subscription, but first need to understand how this ServicePrincipal/Certificate authentication knows which subscription to pull from and/or how to manipulate it?

I can say that when I created the App/ServicePrincipal, I logged in specifying the "DEV" subscription like so:

```
$subscriptionName = "DEV"

$user = "user@company.com"

$password = "*****" 

$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force 

$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($user, $securePassword)

Login-AzureRmAccount -Credential $credential  -SubscriptionName $subscriptionName
```

Comment: I have learned that even though I create the Azure Key Vaults in a given subscription, the "Vault Name" I choose actually must be globally unique.  This explains to me at least why I don't have to supply a Subscription context when retrieving a secret from the vault.